# How to see bounty question counts per tag?

Tags: support, tags, bounty, featured-page

Favorite tags was replaced with tag watching. Now when I go to the featured tab, there's no list of tags in the sidebar sorted by featured question count. I don't have a screenshot, but it looked somewhat like this:

> - [android] x48
> - [javascript] x36
> - [python] x29
> - [php] x10
> - [r] x3

Is it still possible to see tags by bounty question count?

Comment: I still see a list of "related tags" in the sidebar on https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

It's still possible to see the Related Tags section in the sidebar at [`stackoverflow.com/questions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)

I was looking on the homepage ( [`stackoverflow.com`](https://stackoverflow.com) ) My mistake.